# Create menu that looks like Android App Shortcuts in App on button click

Tags: android

Basically, I'm trying to create the app shortcuts UI available in an android app.

I'll like to be able to have a similar popup when tapping the android basic activity (+) button, but the closest thing I've found is the ContextMenu.

I'm not certain if it's a context menu with styling or how to approach it. Any help would be appreciated.

I've had a good look around but could not find an answer.

Thanks!

**Edit**: To clarify since this was marked as a duplicate. I am **not** trying to create launcher shortcuts. I am trying to create a component that looks like launcher shortcuts in the app. For example if a Floating Action Button was pressed.

[image: Image of the UI I mean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This launcher is part of AOSP and You're free to read thru the [`ArrowPopup.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/master/src/com/android/launcher3/popup/ArrowPopup.java) source code.

It might take a bit of digging to find and extract referenced resources, but that's what it is.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find it anywhere